# angular2 can't send message to spring stomp over websocket

Tags: angular, stomp, spring-websocket

I use spring stomp over websocket 8080 port and angular2 4200 port

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/query/company/socket")
        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .withSockJS();
    }

}
```

and :

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" start is : name is : "+message.getName());
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
```

**and angular2:**

```
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
const Stomp = require('stompjs/lib/stomp').Stomp;
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";


    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
      private host='http://localhost:8080';
      private url = `${this.host}/query/company/socket`;
      private subUrl=`${this.host}/topic/greetings`;
      private sendUrl=`${this.host}/app/hello`;
      public stompClient: any;

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.connect();
      }

      connect() {
        var that = this;
        var socket = new SockJS(this.url);
        this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
          console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
          that.stompClient.subscribe(this.subUrl, function (greeting) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
          });
        }, function (err) {
          console.log('err', err);
        });
      }

      public send() {

        this.stompClient.send(this.sendUrl , {},      JSON.stringify({ 'name': 'jack' }));

      }
}
```

when running: chrome console---

```
Web Socket Opened...
stomp.js:134 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000


stomp.js:134 <<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0


stomp.js:134 connected to server undefined
app.component.ts:41 Connected: CONNECTED
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.1


stomp.js:134 >>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:undefined

>>> SEND
destination:http://localhost:8080/app/hello
content-length:13

{"name":"ll"}
```

when sending message :

the spring console:

```
WebSocketSession[1 current WS(1)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 1 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(1)-CONNECTED(1)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 9], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 4, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 2, completed tasks = 441]
```

**when sending message from front , spring should print :**

```
System.out.println(" start is : name is : "+message.getName());
```

but it not ..

and **angular2 did not receive any reply ..**

Comment: You need to add `/hello` as an argument to `enableSimpleBroker()` in order to map messages to that endpoint to your controller.

Comment: I try add `enableSimpleBroker("/topic","/hello");`,  but spring didn't log the receive message from angular2 ..., it may be has no problem, because--I  `@MessageMapping("/hello") ` and `setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");` so ,I send  message to `http://localhost:8080/app/hello` ..

Comment: yeah, you'd need to do that too (or lose the prefix). Is it working with both?

Comment: both not work ...very strange, not knowing why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it .

although my angular2 and spring uses **different port** , 4200 ,8080.

when i change

```
private host='http://localhost:8080';
 private subUrl=`${this.host}/topic/greetings`;
private sendUrl=`${this.host}/app/hello`;
```

to

```
private subUrl='/topic/greetings';
private sendUrl='/app/hello';
```

it works fine ,

**but i do not know the reason .**

Comment: Possibly due to CORS. You may be serving both Angular and the Server app from the same port. So `/topic/greetings` actually resolves to `protocol://host:port//topic/greetings`

Answer (score 1):

I run in the same problem with 2 apps running on different servers. Regardless of angular I also registered the client that way:

```
...
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8099/websocket');
...
stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8099/ws/update', function (msg){
   console.log("received:", msg.body);
});
```

With that binding I did not received any answers from the server even my browser socket tool listed the messages.
But for some reason the subscribtion part should be without the host. Now my code looks like this:

```
...
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8099/websocket');
...
stompClient.subscribe('/ws/update', function (msg){
   console.log("received:", msg.body);
});
```